# Firefox pop-under

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have a simple page:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function popUnder() {
      var adv = window.open('http://google.com', '_blank', 'status = 1, height = 600, width = 600, resizable = 1');
      adv.blur();
      window.focus();
    }
</head>
<body onclick="javascript: popUnder();">
...
</body>
</html>
```

But pop-under not works in Firefox 9.
On this page https://bug369306.bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=296123 all of windows are pop-ups when dom.disable_window_flip == true.
What is the simplest and right way to create pop-unders? Or it is no solutions for creating pop-unders in Firefox with window.open?

Comment: This is 2012, not 1999. Pop-Unders are seen as bad, why are you doing this?

Comment: *"But pop-under not works in Firefox 9"* **Good!!** ;-) Just to avoid jumping to conclusions, what's the use-case? (E.g., why do you need to create a pop-under?) I can't think of a good one, but that doesn't mean there isn't one.

Answer (score 2):

this behaviour was introduced with Firefox 4.

This [workaround](https://gist.github.com/1021924): https://gist.github.com/1021924 still works in FF10.

Answer (score -1):

so i've actually hacked away and got something *somewhat* working in Firefox. i have to say that this was very fast and very ugly, but i don't think i've ever given a good (or even decent) answer on here so may as well try to start. :P also, i should state that i'm triggering the pop under on submission of a form but you could trigger it on page load if you wanted. i have the booleans in there to ensure it doesn't pop under more than once. if anyone wants to clean up my code and show a more straight forward solution (i.e. without multiple booleans/functions and the setTimeout) i'm sure we'd all be grateful.

```
var submitted = false;
var redir = false;
function do_window_location() {
    if(submitted == false) {
        $('form').submit();
        submitted = true;
    }
    window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
}
function call_window_location() {
    if(redir == false) {
        setTimeout('do_window_location()', 100);
        redir = true;
    }
}
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        if(submitted == false) {
            call_window_location();
            $(this).submit();
            submitted = true;
        }
    });
    return true;
});
```

hope this helps someone in some fashion.